# Change color of a character

Tags: jquery, colors

I have the following HTML code:

```
<p>
<label>* Name</label>
</p>
<p>
<label>* Last Name</label>
</p>
<p>
<label>Mascot Name</label>
</p>
```

Is it possible  to change the color only to the character `*` with jQuery?
I tried with the function `find()` but I repeat all the characters on the label.

Comment: When do you need to change the color? Always, or from an event?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you insist on a scripted solution:

```
$("p > label:contains('*')").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("*", "<span class='red'>*</span>"));
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/TxQDV/)

Answer (score 3):

You should rather use css to make this happen.
Use the following instead

```
<label><span style="color:red">*</span> Name</label>
```

This will do the work.

Comment: The last thing you want is to rely on jQuery to implement your styling :) If it's possible with CSS, go for it. Even if you need it to change dynamically, then add a class with `.addClass()` and specify the rules in CSS.

Comment: but it is possible to insert the span looking for the character "*"?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would solve it CSS wise:

```
label:first-letter {

    color: #ff0000;

}
```

Example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_firstletter)

Comment: is also an ingenious but not always see the character "*"

Comment: Although you could use a combination of Karim solution and addClass :)

Answer (score 0):

[Karim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70393/karim79) answer is great, but when implementing it, I noticed it will only select one character within every

tag, so in this case:

```
<p>
  <label>* Name</label>
  <label>* Last Name</label>
  <label>Mascot Name</label>
</p>
```

it wont't work. No problem if you replace the selector with "label:contains('*')" in this case, but what if you want to change the color (or other properties) of **every** instance of that specific character? So in this case:

```
<p>
  * Name<br/>
  * Last Name<br/>
  Mascot Name
</p>
```

you really need something else (I know it doesn't look to good, but this is actual output from Wordpress).
I found this: [Change formatting of a specific character using css or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078438/change-formatting-of-a-specific-character-using-css-or-jquery), 
where [Blazemonger's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901048/blazemonger) answer does the trick! I'll repeat it here:

```
$('selector').html(function(i,el) {
  return el.replace(/\*/g, '<span class="color">*</span>');
});​
```