# Change formatting of a specific character using css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I sometimes build quick and dirty html menus or other types of lists using a pipe | to separate elements, ie:

Home | edit | etc...

I like to make the pipes bold and colored, and wonder if there is a quick way to select a specific character in css styles.  (or maybe JS/jquery)

I do know that I can do this with spans around the pipe, but thought it might be elegant to be able to select just this character.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass a callback function to the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method to wrap those characters in spans for you:

```
$('p.menu').html(function(i,el) {
    return el.replace(/\|/g, '<span class="sp">|</span>');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ymE6y/

Comment: that is awesome...jaw drop here.

Comment: You're welcome -- please don't forget to [accept your favorite answers to your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I'm fairly new to jquery, what are the `i` and `el` arguments doing?

Comment: @user1803405 [It's in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) -- `i` is the (zero-based) index number of the element that's being acted on, while `el` is the original string (and which I should have named `str` instead, but too late now).