# Change color of the 3 middle characters of a dynamic string in JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a string in my C# (ASP.Net Core) project something like below:

`Home Phone is 0098913123456789; Factory Phone:0098352654855 ; Fax: 123456982;`

I would like to show it on client browser something like this:

[image]

More info: I have a `<p>Hello World 00989131234567- Fax: 123456</p>` element . The string contains some
irregular phone numbers, some of them are 11 digits and some else are 8 digits and some are
14 digits. For easy memorizong, I want to stylish/colorize some digits for example the second-three-digits of each phone number in the string by JQuery/JavaScript. It must first finds all the digits, then select some characters of the phone-Number and then changes the color.

Update:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get all digits more than 8 character        
  var result = $("#phoneNumber").text().match(/\d{8,14}/g);
  $.each(result, function(index, value) {
    //Get the 3 digits in the middle of the number
    var temp = value.substring(value.length - 7, value.length - 4);
    $("#phoneNumber").each(function() {
      //change the color
      $(this).html($(this).html().replaceAll(temp, "<span class='w3-text-cyan'>" + temp + "</span>"));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="phoneNumber"> This is a paragraph. First phone is 009812345678 and fax is 12345678</p>
```

Comment: You're going to need to replace the `innerText` with the text and wrap the numbers you want in `spans` and set their `className` to something that coincides with the color you want. - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881171/change-color-of-a-character)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. It made me to answer indirectly. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Ryan Wilson's comment, I would create a set of styles, then for each number create a style value, and then create some spans for each digit (I'm using Razor syntax, but you could use whatever you wish to create the HTML):

```
   var numbers = "00989251234";
   var styles = new string[] 
   { 
      "black", "black", "black", "black", 
      "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
      "black", "black", "black", "black" 
   };

   @for(int x=0;x<numbers.Length;x++)
   {
       <span class="@styles[x]">@numbers[x]</span>
   }
```

Comment: OP also says they are using C# & asp.net.

Comment: My numbers does not have fixed length, I updated the question.